# Truffle deployment/migration error with Infura - contract got deployed once but could not be deployed again

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, infura, hd-wallets

I am stuck when deploying a Smart Contract to **rinkeby** testnet by running (on macOS 12.1) this:

```
sudo truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby
```

The contract compiles and I can deploy it locally, but migration to testnet fails, returning this error:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at createHash (/Users/mac/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/hdkey/lib/hdkey.js:238:1)
    at f.hash160 (/Users/mac/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/hdkey/lib/hdkey.js:39:1)
    at Function.privateKey [as fromMasterSeed] (/Users/mac/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/hdkey/lib/hdkey.js:183:1)
    at Function.fromMasterSeed (/Users/mac/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey.js:18:1)
    at fromMasterSeed (/Users/mac/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/src/index.js:57:1)
    at new checkBIP39Mnemonic (/Users/mac/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/src/index.js:90:1)
    at Object.provider (/Users/mac/learning/Blockchain/TestToken1/truffle-config.js:21:16)
    at Object.getProvider (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:20:1)
    at Object.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:13:1)
    at TruffleConfig.get [as provider] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/configDefaults.js:249:1)
    at Object.detect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/environment/environment.js:19:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:22:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1)
Truffle v5.4.26 (core: 5.4.26)
Node v17.1.0
```

Line 10 of this error message points to my **truffle-config.js** file, in particular to

```
return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/'+infuraKey)
```

I am using Metamask seed phrase and Infura.

In truffle-config.js, I set up rinkeby connection as follows:

```
rinkeby: {
  provider: function () {
    return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/'+infuraKey);
  },
    network_id: 4,       // rinkeby's id
    gas: 600000000,        // rinkeby has a lower block limit than mainnet
    gasPrice: 10000000000
},
```

I have tried:

- setting an env. variable `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`,
- tripple-checking MNEMONIC and Infura key,
- Trying multiple Infura projects, to make sure the same contract is not created for the same ID,
- Increasing gas fees.

Nothing worked so far and suspect the issue is in the sequence of steps I execute the commands.

I suspect the issue is in the sequence I do when setting up the project. I do the following:

1. Run `mkdir project_id`,
2. Run `cd project_id`,
3. Run `truffle init` to initialize a truffle project,
4. Run `npm install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider`,
5. Run `npm install openzeppelin-solidity`,
6. Set up contract and migration files, and truffle-config.js,
7. Run `truffle compile`
8. Run `truffle migrate --reset`
9. Run `truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby`

Initially I thought this could be a Node version issue, but then I managed to run the code successfully once.

### Strange results when running the same code

At one moment, I tried to deploy a simpler contract in a different project to test everything works. After returning to the main project and repeating the **same** Compile->Migrate commands, the contract actually was deployed - I checked this at [etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x441f3EE3423207E6a1a529fCBDfe719fFc982C5c). Unfortunately, I noticed a bug afterwards and had to re-run the Compile->Migrate commands. Then, the error shown above the screenshot appeared again.

I tried subsequently to repeat the sequence again, but was not able to successfully migrate the contract.

### Question

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the work-around - I changed the Node version to the latest stable version (v16) and everything worked like a charm. For those who need to change the version, [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-nvm-macos-with-homebrew/) is a good tutorial.